# Meaning of 再現 in this sentence

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from a conversation with my language partner.
For some context, I told her about our familydinner at a restaurant during christmas eve. I wanted to tell her that you could have your meal freshly cooked right before your eyes there, but unfortunately I used some wrong vocabulary and she explained to me what I actually said :D However, I feel like I don't fully understand what she has written me:
「料理番組で作られた料理」というのは、テレビの料理番組で作っていた料理を再現したという意味でしょうか。

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning 'meals created in a cookery program', doesn't this say that you have reproduced meals which they have made in TV cookery program?"

Since 再現 can also mean "revive. reenact..." I'm not sure if my interpretation is still legit. If it isn't then I probably also misunderstood the whole sentence, that's why I wanted to ask aboutit here :=)

Comment: If you want a good answer, it will only do good to show us what you said **verbatim** even if it is infested with mistakes.   Explaining/summarizing it in English is not helping much if I may be honest.

Comment: Well, I don't think it will help much but I'll post it here in the comments:
彼女の家族は、クリスマスイブでレストランへ行く伝統があります。ですから、去年私の家族と彼女の家族とクリスマスイブで「グルメ-テンプル」というレストランへ行きました。このレストランはビュッフェと料理番組で作られた料理を供して、料理のすごい種々がありました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read your comment, you wrote her that they served you dishes that were made on a cooking show.

She is assuming that you did not mean that the food that you ate was prepared live on a cooking show, so she is asking you this question.

> 「料理番組で作られた料理」というのは、テレビの料理番組で作っていた料理を再現したという意味でしょうか。
>
> By "dishes cooked on a cooking show", do you mean that they were reproducing a dish that was made on a cooking show?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I interpret it perfectly though, you went to the restaurant that chefs recreate the same atmosphere which TV programme does in an amusing way (what I imagine is SMAP-SMAP cooking program, the most famous Japanese-idol group cooks) on christmas eve.

However, it seems to me what she is saying "「料理番組で作られた料理」というのは、テレビの料理番組で作っていた料理を再現したという意味でしょうか。" seems a little bit different. I think what she is saying is that you have made the same meal using the same recipe which they introduced in a TV cookery program.

I believe what I interpret is a normal interpretation of "テレビの料理番組で作っていた料理を再現した" though, I am not so sure about "you have reproduced meals which they have made in TV cookery program" corresponding with it.